# How to reference only a handler from a role in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm using ansible to provision and deploy to a machine. In my provision file I have the role to install pm2.

**provision.yml:**

```
roles:
  - franklinkim.pm2

include:
  - deploy.yml
```

But in the deploy file I update stuff and need to trigger a restart

**deploy.yml:**

```
tasks:
- name: Pull sources from the repository.
  git: repo=https://mygit.com/someproj.net.git dest={{ project_root }}/someproj version={{ branch }} 
  notify:
    - restart pm2
```

Of course if I only run the deploy.yml file then it will fail because it has no reference to `pm2`. I can add the pm2 role in there but that makes no sense, the provision.yml stuff runs as root but the deploy.yml stuff runs as a user.

What's the normal way to handle this? Basically I need to trigger a handler from one playbook that's defined in a role but not execute tasks from that role.

Comment: This is unusual. If you want to restart `pm2` it follows that you have `pm2` installed, which normally means you should be using the role `pm2`. What does `pm2` do?

Comment: I am also wondering why `deploy.yml` isn't a role itself.

Comment: [pm2 is a process manager](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). I have a provision file. It installs the system. I also have a deploy file. It installs the app into the system. It takes 5+ mins to run the provision file even if it does nothing. I only takes 15 seconds to run the deploy file. So, when I'm testing 9 times out of 10 I only want to run the deploy file. When I update the app using the deploy file I need pm2 to restart the app. AFAICT I should be able to use `restart pm2` except I can't do that because it's in the provision file where it belongs.

Comment: I'm using tags in such cases. You can perfectly include both roles in the playbook, and add, say, a `deployonly` tag to the deployment tasks. Then you can add `--tag=deployonly` to the ansible command line.

Comment: Thanks! Yea I just saw about tags. Although funny, even the Ansible [Best Practices page](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html) shows executing different .yml files which completely doesn't appear to work with roles and handlers given the issues shown in my question. I'll switch to tags.

Comment: Args! I thought it would work. Adding a tag to my deploy.yml worked in only executing those things but the pm2 handler is missing even though it's defined in the role. If if I don't do --tag the handler works fine :(  Maybe I need to tag the pm2 role as well but that's kind of stupid. I shouldn't need to execute the install parts of that role just to use the handler parts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the handler in the playbook or in *../handlers/main.yml*.
Of course `pm2` has to be a service on the remote machine and you need sudo permission there.

```
handlers:
  - name: restart pm2
    service: name=pm2 state=restarted
```

Comment: doesn't that defeat the entire point of the roles on ansible-galaxy? If I have to manually add the stuff to each playbook what's the point of having roles at all?

Comment: you can define big handler files and include them into every role if you need to do so, we are using dir handlers with typical handlers for service. We are defining role as service and all handlers are pointing to service needs.

Comment: I'm aware you can defined big handler files. That's not the point. The point is anisble-galaxy roles are supposed to encapsulate everything you need to do for a particular feature. That's their entire point of existing. You're not suppose to have to pull out handlers manually into your own files. You're supposed to be able to reference the ones in the role automatically

Comment: I agree. You could contact the maintainer(s) of that role to add a handler or send a pull request to them. That's where the handler should belong.